# Unable to edit Software Sources (and various other things) due to Run as root - KDE su prompt "Permission denied"

Tags: kde, ubuntu-studio, su

I cannot seem to get any of the KDE su prompts on my Ubuntu Studio install to work. I have set a password for the root account via the terminal and have successfully logged on as root via the terminal like this...

```
su
{enter password}
```

All works great

But graphically I am stuck - The only workaround I have found is to `su` in the terminal and then manually execute the commands.

How can I fix this? There are a few things I am trying to set which I cannot get to at the moment and am having to dig through to find files instead.

Comment: In Ubuntu (and derivatives) the root account is disabled by default. Don't change it. Use `sudo`with your normal user and password whenever you need elevated privileges.

Comment: I normally do exactly that - I am literally trying to click a button in system settings, being prompted for a password via KDE su and it does not work.

Where do I go from here? The password is correct.

I've come from Gnome where this doesn't seem to happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known bug in Ubuntu 22.04. In essence, there was a change in sudo made to patch a security vulnerability, and it also inconveniently threw a wrench in the words of kdesu at the same time. The full report is here, if you're interested: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntustudio-default-settings/+bug/1965439 The developers are actively working to solve the problem.

Currently, there's two workarounds for this.

1. Run the needed commands in a terminal with `sudo`. This is probably the best option until the bug gets ironed out.
2. If you absolutely must have kdesu working normally, you can open the `sudoers` configuration file by doing `sudo nano /etc/sudoers`. Then comment out the line that says `use_pty` in the file, save your changes, and exit. Note that this will open a security hole in your system, the details of which are here: https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2005-4890 It may also mess with stuff if sudo gets updated in the future. As a result, this is not the method I would recommend, but if you're determined to do it this way, here you go.

EDIT: This bug has has a fix released in the latest development release of Kubuntu, by disabling the `use_pty` option in `/etc/sudoers`. Having talked to the developers on IRC, I know that they considered the security implications of this before doing it. As a result, I still don't recommend option 2 because of the potential for upgrade problems involving sudo, but I no longer think the security concerns of option 2 are a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the info - I'll track this.

I've been working around it by checking the execution name in the kdesu prompt and executing that directly via the command line with sudo where I can and su where I can't.

It's not my daily driver distro so it's a manageable temporary annoyance.

Answer (score 1):

Keith, I have the same problem. My current workaround is to edit the .desktop file ( /usr/share/applications/[file-name-here.desktop] of the offending program.

In my case it was ksystemlog and grub-customizer.

Just comment out the line "X-KDE-SubstituteUID=true".

It works but it completely removes the password prompt (only for that particular program) so beware.